# AngularJS performance: How to update only the scopes I know need to be updated?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular scope containing two things:

- a **giant table** with 10k rows that takes a second to render
- some **small extra information** on top of it in a fixed overlay header bar

Depending on how far you have scrolled down the page/table, I have to update one of the small info bits in the header; you can think of it as a % counter how far you've scrolled.

To get the current scroll position, I have written a directive (you can also find it [here](https://gist.github.com/nh2/5501079)):

```
app.directive "setWindowScroll", ->
  restrict: "E"
  scope:
    setVariable: "="

  link: (scope) ->
    $(window).scroll ->

      scope.$apply ->
        scope.setVariable = $(window).scrollTop()
```

My problem is that this makes scrolling around in the table u**nsuably slow**. This is because the veriable I write to with my directive is in the extra-info in the scope, and changing that seems to cause angular to dirty-check the whole table for changes when my `$apply` is called.

I know that this scrolling will never change anything in my table, and would like to restrict my `$apply` to affect the header part of my site.

How can I make angular **not** dirty check the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular does the dirty checking under a process called digest. When you do a call to `$scope.$digest()` it will propagate to every child scope of `$scope`. To notify angular about changes you usually do a `$scope.$apply()`. At the end of the $apply() angular does a digest on the root scope, which triggers a diggest on every scope in your application. So to avoid the digest on in your scope with the big table scope, you should make sure that it is not the child of the extra information scope, and rather than doing an $scope.$apply() in your directive you could do a $scope.$digest(). This might be a bit confusing so I've made a plunker that tries to show the difference. Open your console and see the difference in the scroll event and button click:

http://plnkr.co/edit/45gKhAIt0DrozS7f0Bz2?p=preview

```
// this will only cause a digest in the current scope and its children
angular.element($window).bind('scroll',function(){
  $scope.scrollY = $window.scrollY;
  $scope.$digest();
})

// this will cause a digest in every scope
angular.element($window).bind('scroll',function(){
  $scope.scrollY = $window.scrollY;
  $scope.$apply();
})
```

When all this is said, it's a very unusual thing to do - and probably not a good idea for a number of reasons (angular doesnt scale well with thousands of elements, you can't use any of the angular event directives (ngClick etc) because they're all wrapped in $apply) - but if you can't render the table on the server side you can give this a try.

Comment: Had to open the plunker in a new window to get a scroll bar in firefox: http://run.plnkr.co/4CAAfTuXNmgfGdql/

Comment: The new window link didn't work for me. [This](http://beta.plnkr.co/45gKhAIt0DrozS7f0Bz2) and http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/45gKhAIt0DrozS7f0Bz2/ did.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer explaining that so well. I put my header into its own scope and indeed using `$digest` instead of `$apply` fixes my problems. However, you are very right with what you say at the end - being not able to use *anything* that calls `$apply` is not feasible and very constraining. Since my table is mostly not going to change, I will try to render the table in the browser, but without data bindings (either by detaching watchers after creation, writing a custom `ng-repeat`-like directive, or using a more primitive, non-binding templating engine for the table only).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if this is possible to do too, but -- regardless -- you might want to consider not drawing the entire table all at once.

Instead limit it (and the amount of associated data/controllers in Angular-world) to just the rows that are visible based on current scroll position + some cached rows above and below. You can still keep all the data in an array on the client, but only expose a small subset to Angular at any time.

One way to do it might be to have a small array in Angular-world which you render using `ng-repeat`, and then you add and remove elements in this small angular array from the big non-angular array based on scroll position.

This way Angular only knows about a small subset of your data, and should render much faster. I think this should work quite well in general because it's also much less work for the browser which doesn't need to maintain a DOM tree and rendering for 10k rows.

Comment: Generally you are right and I thought about this as well, but in this case I need to replicate an existing UI which had the same table, and it is indeed very snappy as long as I don't trigger this accidental dirty check all the time by updating something outside of the table.